# Cannot read .xlsx file with read_excel()

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

I want to open the .xlsx file through read_excel().

However, an error message is printed even though the openpyxl and pandas packages are installed.

The pandas version is 0.24.2 and the openpyxl version is 3.0.10.

The error message is - ValueError: Unknown engine: openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd
import math

retail_df = pd.read_excel('./Online_Retail.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
print(retail_df.head())
```

Comment: Your code looks OK however the pandas version 0.24.2 is from 2019, its about  40 releases (4 years) old. Have you tried the latest release,1.5 (1.5.3)?

Comment: That's right. It was a version problem and it worked fine when I upgraded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas 0.24.2 the default engine is openpyxl and for that, you don't need to set it up manually during loading the excel file inside the read_excel() function.

So now your updated working code for reading excel files is :

```
import pandas as pd
import math

retail_df = pd.read_excel('./Online_Retail.xlsx')
print(retail_df.head())
```

**Testing result from my side with this code.**
[image]